# Navigation property in optional:optional where only one table has foreign key

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to define the following model where Appointment table has foreign key for Person, and the entities both have navigation properties to each other.

```
public class Appointment
{
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key property (this will be created in DB)
    public int? PersonId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property to Flatmate
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    // Just navigation property. Don't want Person table to include foreign key (no need)
    public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
}
```

I try to use fluent config:

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.Person)
            .WithOptionalDependent(p=> p.Appointment);
```

But I get an exception that its missing a column (either Appointment_AppointmentId or Person_PersonId, depending on whether I use WithOptionalDependent or WithOptionalPrincipal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't support this. `HasOptional().WithOptionalDependent()` can work when both tables use the same key (`PersonId == AppointmentId`), but that's not the situation you have. In order to ensure that one person doesn't have multiple appointments, you'd need to make sure `PersonId` is unique in the `Appointment` table, and Entity Framework doesn't support unique constraints.

What you could do (without changing your database) is map this as a one-to-many relation, where one person can have multiple appointments, and create a helper property to return the one appointment:

```
public virtual ICollection<Appointments> Appointments { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public Appointment Appointment {
    get {
        return Appointments.SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Note that Entity Framework won't understand the `Appointment` property, so you cannot use it in queries.